# PHP Pagination Displays in Wrong Order After Certain Page

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, pagination

I have been making my own pagination in PHP with SQL and PDO. However, after a certain number of pages the results start to be ordered back to front. Meaning the bottom record should be at the top.

Here is my SQL (Ordered by primary id in the table):

```
$prepareStatement = $db_connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM " . $databaseTableName . " ORDER BY " . $databaseOrderBy . " DESC LIMIT ?, ?");
```

Then I use PHP PDO to create an array like so:

```
$dataRows = $prepareStatement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Then I output the data like this:

```
for($i = 0; $i <= $rowCount - 1; $i++)
{
        echo $i . " ";
                    //Output the data with HTML...
        echo '
        <div class="messageDisplayBoxReportError">

          <p class="reportErrorTime">' . $dataRows[$i]["time"] . '</p>

          <P class="reportErrorDate">' . $dataRows[$i]["date"] . '</p>

          <p><b>Message From: ' . $dataRows[$i]["name"] . ' | Email: ' . $dataRows[$i]["email"] . '</b></p>

          <p>' . $dataRows[$i]["message"] . '</p>

        </div>';
}
```

An example of my problem is that I have 47 records in my table, and I have set it to display 4 records per page, this comes to 12 pages with the last page only having 3 records instead of 4 as there are only 3 left. This all works but when I get to page 6 and onward the records start to display back to front.

The data outputs like this and the bottom record should be at the top:
[image]

This happens from page 6 and on wards. I cannot understand why this is happening as it doesn't happen until I get to page 6. All pages before page 6 display in order correctly. I have my SQL statement set to order them using DESC and cannot see why this is not working.

Thanks if you can help me!

Comment: Did you sort the records and output them in the database itself without running through your pagination script? Can something be causing the data order to be off?

Comment: Well I order the data by the primary id and when the data is inserted it is not ordered or anything just inserted in. That is why I chose to order it by DESC order.

Comment: Can we see the script you use to make the navigation buttons?

Comment: I'm not sure but now I think about it, is this how it is to suppose output anyway? The only reason I notice this was because I saw that the results were back to front after a certain number of pages. So I saw the change and could not tell if this was an error or just how it is supposed to be?

Comment: As you are NOT displaying `$databaseOrderBy` how do you know that the there is an _error_ ?

Comment: What do you mean? I stated in the sub title that "Here is my SQL (Ordered by primary id in the table):"  ?